# Can we hide the three dots from the ellipsis property

Tags: html, css, sass

Can we hide the three dots coming from `text-overflow: ellipsis` property?? without using clipping.

Our text is "Lorem ipsum dolor".
"Lorem ips..." with the ellipsis property and With the clip property the text will be "Lorem ipsum d". But I want "Lorem ipsum"  text. Can we acheive this by anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; you can change what the string to use as ellipsis by doing `text-overflow: ellipsis "ellipsis string"`. However, it might be better just to use `text-overflow: ""` because its behavior is better suited to not having anything there.

Here's the [text-overflow documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, I went through this. But ig this will be supported for only firefox right ?

Comment: Try setting `text-overflow: clip` as only Firefox supports setting the overflow character as a string for now.